# How to handle non-existent data in JSONParser in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a JSONParser method like this :

```
 public ArrayList<Meaning> parseMeaning (JSONObject object)
    {
        ArrayList<Meaning> arrayList = new ArrayList<Meaning>();

        try
        {
            JSONObject value = object.getJSONObject("Value");
            JSONArray meaningArray = value.getJSONArray("Meanings");
            JSONObject meaningobj = null;

            for(int i = 0; i < meaningArray.length(); i++) {
                meaningobj = meaningArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Meaning myMeaning = new Meaning();

                myMeaning.MeaningID = meaningobj.getInt("MeaningID");
                myMeaning.Type1 = meaningobj.getInt("Type1");
                myMeaning.Type2= meaningobj.getInt("Type2");

                arrayList.add(myMeaning);
            }

        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.d("JSONParser=>parseMeaning", e.getMessage());
        }

        return arrayList;

    }
```

My meaning class is like this :

```
public class Meaning {
   public int MeaningID;
   public Integer Type1;
   public Integer Type2;
}
```

When I run the code, some JSON Objects don't have Type2 value (because they were null in the database). So I get this exception :

> D/JSONParser=>parseMeaning﹕ No value for Type2

Can you tell me how I should handle such situations when there is no value for a field? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `has` method of `JSONObject`.

E.g. :

```
if(meaningobj.has("Type2")){

myMeaning.Type2= meaningobj.getInt("Type2");

}
```